# Set a number of CSS styles based on class

Tags: css, reactjs, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, react-bootstrap

I have an application which shows information about sports people who are related to particular teams.  It is a React app and uses React Bootstrap 4 for the front-end styles.

I would like to be able to style a number of page elements according to the player's team colors, pseudo-code:

```
.team1 {
  primary-color: #773141;
  secondary-color: #ffb612;
}

.team2 {
  primary-color: #145131;
  secondary-color: #gbb894;
    }
```

and then apply these primary and secondary colours to H1s, borders etc.

I can mock up the effect I'm looking for by hacking the CSS in the browser and would like to apply the below styles (but perhaps replacing the hex values with reference to that team's primary or secondary colours?)

```
div.card-header>h1 {
  color: #ffb612;
}

div.card-header>h2 {
  color: #ffb612;
}

body {
  background-color: #ffb612;
}

.card {
  background-color: #773141;
}

.card-footer {
  color: #ffb612;
}
```

The React app is mounted in index.html in the standard way:

```
<body>
  <noscript>You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.</noscript>
  <div id="root"></div>
```

What is the best way to achieve this?  Sorry, I'm really not an experienced front-end dev!

Comment: I hope you are using the var symbols for primary color and secondary color.

Comment: @m4n0 I'm not that's pseudo-code.  I don't know anything about var symbols in CSS.  Is that what I should be doing?

Comment: That could improve your efforts. Yes!